# Need specific signature for service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, soa

I have been getting into WCF and have been noticing that no matter what service code I download and try, none of them show up in the Task Manager under services, even when I select "Show processes from all users".  I would like to have my service be opening visible under "Services" and I want to be able to control the name and description.  This is so when an admin logs into the box they will be able to check there to find it and readily see that it is either running or not running.

When I began reading my WCF book, I just assumed that a non IIS hosted windows service would naturally be hooked up to windows in that way.  Is there something I am missing?  Is it something as simple as a registry entry, or is it the paradigm with which the service is programmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services you see in task managers are windows services - UI-less daemons that can run without a user logged on. These are completely different from WCF services which are a way to expose functionality over defined endpoints. Unfortunately the world of IT has a number of name collisions like this - which can confuse people when they first start using a technology

Somewhat confusingly you can also host one of more WCF services inside a windows service

There is no UI for viewing non-IIS hosted services that are running (IIS hosting has Windows Server AppFabric). If you want this functionality you would have to build it yourself

You can create a Windows service using the windows service project type in Visual Studio.

A WCF service needs a process to host it. For demos its common to use Console applications. However for production use people use either IIS or a Windows Service. Using a Console app or a Windows Service is known as self hosting. Using IIS is known either as IIS or WAS hosting

There is a how-to for hosting WCF in a Windows Service [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)

There is some general info about hosting options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158)

Comment: This s good to know and clears up some confusion for me.  My remaining question related to this is: Can I program a daemon in c#? Is it better to write a daemon that contains or hosts wcf services?  What are the advantages and disadvantages to wrapping wcf inside a daemon?

Comment: I added some more detail to my response